# How to direct download the pdf file instead of redirecting it to new page using carrierwave in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using [carrierwave](http://richonrails.com/articles/allowing-file-uploads-with-carrierwave) for uploading and downloading the files.
I am able to download all the files directly. But in case of pdf files, when I click on download it is redirecting to new page asking for open with, download and etc fields.
Is there any way to direct download pdf files? (which is my client requirement)

My controller:

```
  def show
 @invoice_detail = InvoiceDetail.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @invoice_detail }
    format.pdf { render :layout => false }
  end
  end
```

attachment_uploader.rb:

```
 def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  def extension_white_list
    %w(xlsx pdf doc htm html docx png jpg jpeg xls)
  end
  def filename
  "#{model.invoice_number}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'download file', invoice_details.attachment_url %>
```

Comment: do you want the controller to return a pdf? you can use send_file for that: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file

Answer (score 2):

Use following line in show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'download file', invoice_details.attachment_url, download: invoice_details.attachment_url, target: "_blank" %>
```

Above only works with HTML 5. more info http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_download.asp

**EDIT:**
  If you want to remove the open/download prompt than it's not possible. It's browser's configuration.

Comment: I asked how to direct download instead of asking "open with", "download" options. If we give target blank, it will go to new page.

Comment: yep umm.. you can remove 'target' attribute.... the *download* attribute is the answer, it will actually prompt the download window

Comment: and if you are asking how to remove the "open with" window. It's not possible. Because actually that is browser/OS's configuration on which you do not have control.

Comment: I'm not asking how to remove. I mean how to directly download without asking for the options like "open with", "download" etc;

Comment: That's not possible mate. It's browser's config. Only user can change it! you have no control over it!!!